# .NET Windows Forms: How to get other running applications information?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

Is there a way to get information about other running applications? for example: have my windows form application list all the running applications and their windows size.

Firefox: (info here)

Notepad: (info here)

I want to ultimately tile all open windows.
Thanks!

Comment: There is a Win32 function, TileWindows ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633554(v=vs.85).aspx ), that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve a list of the processes running on the current machine by using

System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()

See this msdn link for [further info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses.aspx)

Comment: That was the namespace I needed. Thank you!